# I need to search Student from Table1 and Teacher in Table2

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio

`Dim qstr As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID ='" & Textbox.Text &"'"`

how to insert Table2 in that line code?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Students INNER JOIN Teachers ON Students.TeacherID = Teachers.ID WHERE ...
```

You can use different types of joins to get the results you want.